# Mail Delivery Subsystem blocks email from Apps Script MailApp

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue where my `MailApp.sendEmail` call is getting blocked by Google's Delivery Services. The [specific error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcHCU.png) I get:

```
Message rejected. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.
Final-Recipient: rfc822; ******@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic Code: smtp; Message rejected. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.
Last-Attempt-Date: ......
```

The linked answer page redirects to [this one](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596) which suggests I have an issue with my address formatting, or that my email content looks suspicious.

As you can probably see below everything is formatted to the bare minimum, so none of the ... and space preceding or following the e-mail should be an issue.  I haven't been able to find any fixes for this situation and regardless of who I put in my `"to:"` field, it seems to break. For example, if I put my second e-mail address in as `"to:"`, it still gets blocked on my side. Code snippet below.

```
var mailbody = formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "mygmail@gmail.com",
  subject: "Contact form submitted",
  htmlBody: mailbody
});
```

HTML Formatting:

```
for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the email is getting **blocked**? Or is the code which calls that snippet you show even executed? If so, how?

Comment: It is being blocked, I am able to get this reply as spam originally but I allowed it through. I am worried that it'll be flagged as a bot account or something.  It goes through still but is cluttered because of this format and will not be practical to expand upon unless I can sort it out. [Link of flag](https://imgur.com/a/SFv2BzP)